# Problem with PiecewiseExpand[Max[ ]]

Tags: piecewise, maximum

I have these functions:

[image]

[image]

By running this command:

```
FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[Max[a, b , c, x, y, z]], 
 9 <= \[Beta] <= 11]
```

I obtain:
[image]

However I think the funtion 1/10000000000 is the maximum also from 10 to 10.000000000000270. To test this I run:

```
\[Beta] = 10.00000000000015
Max[a, b , c, x, y, z]
```

and, indeed, I obtain 1/10000000000 as a result.

Interestingly, when I drop either `a` or `b` or `c` from the `PiecewiseExpand`, I obtain what I think is the correct result: 
[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post (complete) code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right, I am going to update the question.